# How to pass URL variable to django admin Inline form?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to pre-populate values in an admin form from URL parameters. For normal fields, this works by simply adding /?field_name=value parameters to the URL. However, my field is located in a Admin Inline Formset within the form. Is there any way to pass URL parameters through to the Inline Form? For example:

models.py:

```
class Parent(Model):
    ...

class Child(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=20)
    provenance = ManyToManyField('Provenance')

class Provenance(Model):
    child = ForeignKey(Child)
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent)
```

admin.py:

```
class ProvenanceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Provenance
    form = myforms.ProvenanceForm
    ...

class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = myforms.ChildForm
   [inlines] = ProvenanceInline
   ...
```

Now, I have a custom view for showing the Parent object and within this view, I would like to have a link for creating a Child of that Parent. In theory, this would work:

```
<a href="{%url 'admin:myapp_child_add'%}?parent={{origin.pk}}">Add Child</a>
```

The problem is that the "parent" field is hidden within the InlineAdmin Formset. How can I make ProvenanceForm see the URL variable passed to ChildForm?

I tried overriding `get_formset` in the ProvenanceInline or modifying `get_inline_instances` in the ChildAdmin but I am not getting anywhere. (BTW, my ChildForm is modified so that it gets the `request` variable passed into its constructor. Perhaps `self.request` could be used here, too). Any suggestions are welcome!